# C# Array - identify the input if it is repeating or not

Tags: c#

I want to create an algorithm that would identify if the user input is repeating or not. If it is repeating it will prompt the user a message if its not repeating it will continue the process.

```
public static class Program 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("input array of numbers: );

        int[] array = new int[4];

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if(array[i] == array[0])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("repeating inputs")
            }
        }                     
        Console.WriteLine("Highest number is:" + array.MaxLenght);           
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Explanation: The user will be prompted by message "inter array of numbers:" then the user will now input the numbers. If the user inputs the same number or if the number was already inputted, the user will be prompted by a message something like "repeating inputs! Input another number". After the user input another number unique to the previously interred the program will continue and print out the largest number base on the inputs.

Comment: Use a temporary variable to receive the input, then run a loop over the element already inserted (i-1) and check one by one if the value in the temporary variable is already there

Comment: And what is your problem? Doesn´t this code does what it should? What do you expect and what do you get instead? Anyway: what do you mean by "repeating"? Is 4,4,3,3 repeating? Or 4,1,4,1? Or 9,9,1,2? Or only 9,9,9,9?

Comment: Here's the output i need:  the user will be prompted by message "inter array of numbers:" then the user will now input the numbers. If the user inputs the same number or if the number was already inputed, the user will be prompted by a message something like "repeating inputs! Input another number". After the user input another number unique to the previously intered the program will continue and print out the largest number base on the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if I understood you correctly but this is what i can extrapolated from your post : 
you want to get input from the user and check if it's repeating or not and then print the highest number (based on your  Console.WriteLine("Highest number is:" + array.MaxLenght); )

this is how i'd approach it

```
Console.WriteLine("input array of numbers: ");
        List<int> uniqueInts = new List<int>();
        int[] array = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (!uniqueInts.Contains(array[i]))
                uniqueInts.Add(array[i]);
        }

        //getting the max number
        //assuming the first number is the max
        int max = uniqueInts[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < uniqueInts.Count; i++)
        {
            if (max < uniqueInts[i])
                max = uniqueInts[i];
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The highest number is : " + max);
```

Comment: Here the output i need:

Comment: Here's the output i need:  the user will be prompted by message "inter array of numbers:" then the user will now input the numbers. If the user inputs the same number or if the number was already inputed, the user will be prompted by a message something like "repeating inputs! Input another number". After the user input another number unique to the previously intered the program will continue and print out the largest number base on the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of assumptions that I'm making with this answer. I'm assuming you're struggling to get the value of the item prior to the current iteration considering you have `if(array[i] == array[0])`.

If that's the case, then simply change `array[0]` to `array[i-1]`.

Wait! Before you do that, you need to add a check to make sure you aren't on the first iteration. If you don't, you'll get an exception thrown on the first iteration, because you'll be trying to grab `array[-1]`, which isn't valid.

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
   array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   if(i > 0)
   {
       if (array[i] == array[i-1])
           Console.WriteLine("repeating inputs")
   }
}
```

Make these few changes, and I think you'll get what you're after.